# A parity counting problem for subsets over finite fields

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, finite-fields, enumerative-combinatorics

Let ${\mathbb F}_p$ be the prime field of $p$ elements and $b$ be an element in ${\mathbb F}_p$.
 For a subset $T\subseteq {\mathbb F}_p$, define
$$Bias(T)=|N_e( {\mathbb F}_p,b)-N_o( {\mathbb F}_p,b)|,$$
where $$N_e( {\mathbb F}_p,b)=\#  \{ D\subseteq  {\mathbb F}_p | \sum_{x\in D}x=b, |D\cap
T|\equiv 0 \bmod 2 \}$$ and  $$N_o( {\mathbb F}_p,b)=\#\{ D\subseteq  {\mathbb F}_p|
\sum_{x\in D}x=b, |D\cap T|\equiv 1 \bmod 2 \}.$$

My question: is there any method to prove $$Bias(T)\leq 2^{(1/2+o(1))p}, \forall T \ne \emptyset$$ for $|T|\sim p/2$? Thank you very much.

The exponential sum approach by Shparlinski can be used to show $$Bias(T)\leq 2^{0.8413p}.$$

When $|T|$ is very small, say for example, $|T|=o(p)$, or very large $(|T|=p-o(p))$, this conjecture can be solved by our sieving counting argument.

Take the simplest example, $T={\mathbb F}_p$, and we count that $$N_e({\mathbb F}_p, b)=\sum_{k\ne 0, 2\mid k} {1\over p}{p\choose k}\pm 1=\frac { 2^{p-1}-1}p\pm 1,$$ 
$$N_o({\mathbb F}_p, b)=\sum_{k\ne p, 2\not\mid k} {1\over p}{p\choose k}\pm 1=\frac {2^{p-1}-1}p\pm 1,$$ and thus 
$$Bias({\mathbb F}_p) \leq 2.$$

Generally we may define $$Bias_S(T)=|N_e(S,b)-N_o(S,b)|$$ similarly for $S\subseteq {\mathbb F}_p$ and propose the same conjecture $Bias_S(T)=2^{(1/2+o(1)|S|}, \forall T\ne \emptyset$.

Comment: I'm not sure if my calculations are correct, but picking $T$ to be the elements in the interval $(\frac{p}{4},\frac{3p}{4})$ should give you a bias $~2^{cp}$ for $b=0$.

Comment: @Gjergji: Great! Did you get an explicit bound on $c$?

Answer (score 6):

Let's identify the elements of $\mathbb F_p$ with $\lbrace 0,1,2,\dots ,p-1\rbrace$. After fixing $T\subset \mathbb F_p$ and $b$, the Bias can be read off the following generating function
$$f_{T,b}(x)=x^{p-b}\prod_{i=0}^{p-1} \left(1+(-1)^{\chi(i)}x^i\right),$$
where $\chi(i)=1$ if $i\in T$, and $\chi(i)=0$ otherwise.

In fact $\operatorname{Bias}(T,b)=\frac{1}{p}\left|\sum_{i=0}^{p-1} f_{T,b}(\omega^i)\right|$, where $\omega$ is a primitive $p$th root of unity. Notice for example that if $0\in T$, then the Bias evaluates to zero (adding/removing zero gives a bijection between even/odd sets).

To disprove your conjecture we can look at the set $T=\lbrace t | \frac{p}{4} \leq  t \leq \frac{3p}{4}\rbrace$, and set $b=0$. Using that $\prod_{i=0}^{p-1}(1+\omega^i)=2$, we can say
$$\operatorname{Bias}(T,0)=\frac{2}{p}|\sum_{i=0}^{p-1}\prod_{t\in T} \frac{(1-\omega^{it})}{(1+\omega^{it})}|.$$
From here you can check that: (1) every term in the sum is nonnegative, so we may ignore the absolute value (2) the term for $i=1$ is $\left(\prod_{t\in T} \frac{1-\cos(2\pi t/p)}{1+\cos(2\pi t/p)}\right)^{1/2}>(1+\sqrt{2})^{p/8}=2^{O(p)}$.

Comment: Very good example and thank you very much. I am so sorry that I made a typo on the magnitude of $Bias(T)$. The right conjecture should be: is there any method to prove $$Bias(T)=2^{(1/2+p(1))p}, \forall T\ne \emptyset$$ for $|T|\sim p/2$? Of course we can still ask for which kind of $T$ $$Bias(T)=2^{o(p)}.$$

Comment: Is the 1/2 by analogy with a sum of random $\pm 1$ terms, or is there some other reason as well?

Comment: @Kevin: Yes, it's by the analogy with a sum of random coin flipping. If for all $T$, $Bias(T)\leq 2^{o(p)}$, this will lead a contradiction to the bounds on small biased set.

Comment: @Gjergji: Thank you again for your answer. Could you put this answer as a comment so that keep this problem unanswered? I shall then update my question.

Comment: @Joe, the same method still applies. For any $T$ the terms in the sum above are bounded by $2^{o(1)+p/2}$.

Comment: @Gjergji: Could you please give me more details? It seems not direct to get an upper bound in your example. Shparlinski obtained an upper bound (mentioned in the question) by this way in a dual sense. Your example gives roughly the lower bound $2^{0.159p}$.